# Loading and displaying data (QSqlTableModel)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to load and display data from a ODBC source (informix db).
I can create and open the connection. But I've some problems with QSqlTableModel. 
The following code compiles and run without errors but don't display any data. The columns from my table are displayed in the QTableView. (1 and 3)
When I use QSqlQueryModel (2) I get data from my table, so connection works and I'm on the correct DB.

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong or what I have to do to display my data with QTableView? 
This is my first use of Qt. I'm using Qt under windows with MinGW compiler, but with MSVC the result is the same.

```
this->_connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
_connection.setDatabaseName("CargoSoft cs-entw");
_connection.open();

// 1.)
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(this, _connection);
model->setTable("eakopf_t");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("mandant"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("positionsnummer"));

// 2.)
QSqlQueryModel queryModel;
queryModel.setQuery("SELECT * FROM eakopf_t");
QString mandant = queryModel.record(4).value("mandant").toString();

// 3.)
QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(model);
//view->hideColumn(0); // don't show the ID
view->show();
```

Comment: As I understand, `_connection.open()` returns true?

Comment: Yes, it returns true.

Comment: Your code (copied from documentation) is normal, it works, so check what returns `model->select();`. If it returns false, then call `lastError() `to know what happens, but if it returns true, than I don't know what is wrong here

Comment: Ok, select() == false and the message I get says: "Forward-only queries cannot be used in a data model". Found the problem. ^^ I've to set "scrollable cursors" in my ODBC driver... Thank's for your help.

Comment: then I think that my task is completed here, I helped you find this error, and I posted it as answer, but I added one (maybe) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works normal. To know what exactly happens, I suggest you to check `model->select();`. If it returns `false` then you should call `lastError()` method and get human readable error string.

A few words about your current problem. Unfortunately, I don't see this error before, but I can give you solution from russian forum, maybe it helps you in your research.

Link: http://www.forum.crossplatform.ru/lofiversion/index.php/t3501.html

Solutions: try to set forward only queries with this:

```
model->query().setForwardOnly(true);
```

or this

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.prepare( ... );
q.setForwardOnly( true );
model->setQuery( q );
```

Hope it helps.